# Any possible adj of encourage?

Tags: meaning, adverbs

I would like to know an proper equivalent adjective of the verb called '**encourage**'

For example: I am talking with my friend about a topic as follows:

> **Me**: This topic makes me encourage for investigating a novel technique. Let's delve into!
>
> **Him**: Indeed, the topis is very [ **encourageable** | **encouraging** ].

Which adjective is correct to express about what the topic is?
Or Do you know any other words to express the meaning?

Comment: The Me: bit doesn't really make sense

Comment: @Hakan Perhaps you're thinking of "intriguing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think, as *@akkatracker* said, your *"Me"* sentence doesn't make sense. I think the answer's *@JoeMcMahon* might be the right sentence like:

```
Me: This topic encourages me to investigate a novel technique. Let's delve into it!
```

Then, (because it's really the topic of your issue) the first answer could to be **"encouraging"**.
However, to use other adjectives and be as near as possible to the verb **"encourage"** *(vb transitive)*, you need to know exactly what does it means:

> to **inspire** (someone) with the courage or confidence (to do something).
>   to **stimulate** (something or someone to do something) by approval or help; support.

In your case, you want to investigate a novel technique because this topic *inspires* you or it *stimulates* you *to learn something*. With the help of this topic, learning a novel technique doesn't seem difficult, so you say "Let's go! We will have fun to learn this". And if *"Him"* has the same enthusiast than yours, he might say:

```
Him: Indeed, the topic is very inspiring.
```

or

```
Him: Indeed, the topic is very stimulating.
```

Also, you can say (roughly and in a good way:) *"This topic pushes me to do this"*, so you can use adjectives as: *"exciting"*, *"inviting"*, *"inciting"*, and *"attractive"*.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure about stimulating in this context. The topic may stimulate conversation or thought, but I'm not a fan of the topic being stimulating by itself... It doesn't sound right to me, perhaps because of the other meanings of the word stimulate.

Comment: Indeed, you're right because "stimulating" *(from stimulate: to excite (a nerve, organ, etc))* is a physiological/psychological reference. However, this adjective is also often used **metaphorically**. For example, an interesting or fun activity can be described as stimulating, regardless of its physical effects. When you look at the definition of "encourage": *stimulate with help, support of something*, you can mean that it will be stimulating to do *with the aid of* it, because it will be easy. Therefore, you can consider that the topic is a *stimulus*.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're communicating is that the topic has made you feel that a novel approach may lead to a solution if one uses it. Have I got that right? If so, I might say it this way:

```
This topic encourages me to try a novel technique. Let's try it!
```

Answer (score 0):

*"encouragable"* is definitely wrong

*"encouraging"* could be used, but it's not the best choice here, if I understand correctly what you're trying to say:

- a solution can seem encouraging (= you think it will work)
- an encouraging topic sounds a bit awkward, but might be ok in a particular situation, eg. if you're looking for topics for your thesis, and you think that this specific topic will be a good one to work on
- in such cases, *"encouraging"* could be used to mean *"promising"*

Other words you might want to use instead are: *"intriguing"*, *"compelling"*, *"fascinating"* (though note that you shouldn't say **"very fascinating"*, just *"fascinating"*), or even plain old *"interesting"*.

That being said, the Me: part of your example dialog is written in very awkward/incorrect English. Might I suggest:

```
Me: This topic makes me interested in investigating a novel technique. Let's delve into it!

Him: Indeed, the topic is very compelling.
```